# How to get a random CGFloat for a constraint?

Tags: ios, swift2, arc4random, cgfloat

I'm trying to randomize a leading constraint for a button in swift. To activate this I am selecting a button. When I select the button for the first time, it works well, but all the times after this, it shows a lot of errors in the NSLog. Here's the code:

```
let button = UIButton()
@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
     let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(180) + 30)
     let cgfloatrandom = CGFloat(randomNumber)
     button.hidden = false
     button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: cgfloatrandom),
        button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 390),
        button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75),
        button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75)
        ])
}
```

Please help. Thank you. Anton

Comment: you have to remove the previously added constraint on the second run because the previous one will conflict with the new one. The first one says "200 pixel away", the second one says "100 pixel away": that is not going to end well ;) What you should do is create the constraint in the interface builder, connect it as outlet and change only the constant on that outlet instead of creating new constraints all the time

Comment: @ luk2302 Like this?: `button.removeConstraints([button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor)])`

Comment: why not just hold the leading constraint and then change the "constant" value?

Comment: maybe, try it. I have 0 experience creating and removing constraints via code - I always only change them

Comment: @ Christian 'fuzi' Orgler How would I do that (I'm still kind of new to constraints in swift)?

Comment: It is really inefficient to remove and re-add constraints. Definitely keep a reference to one leading constraint and simply change its `constant`.

Comment: @Joey Can I do this to a created button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're adding constraints to a button that already has been properly constrained. While you could remove all the constraints and recreate them, that is really inefficient and would not be recommended.

I would recommend simply keeping a reference to the leading constraint, which will allow you to access it every time the button is tapped to modify the `constant`.

To do this, implement a property for your leading constraint, like so:

```
var leadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

When you create this button, you'll want to properly constrain it as well. Here is where you'll be creating that special leading constraint. This is done outside of the button action function, perhaps in `viewDidLoad`:

```
button = UIButton() 
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//...

leadingConstraint = button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)

NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
    leadingConstraint,
    button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 390),
    button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75),
    button.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(75)
])
```

Now when the button is tapped, you won't need to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, and you can simply update the `constant` of the existing leading constraint.

```
@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
     button.hidden = false

     let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(180) + 30)
     leadingConstraint.constant = CGFloat(randomNumber)
}
```

Comment: Great description! Thanks!